# How to return a list of lists that has both string and int in each list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

For example, if I have :

```
a=['ab','bc','cd']
b=[[1,23],[2,3,4],[23,4]]
```

Want to get:

```
result=[['ab',[1,23]], ['bc',[2,3,4]],['cd',[23,4]]]
```

Each list in list includes a string and a list of int.
How can I get this result?

Answer (score 2):

This is what zip is used for. Use `zip(a,b)` will get:

```
[('ab', [1, 23]), ('bc', [2, 3, 4]), ('cd', [23, 4])]
```

which is a list of tuple. You can do `[list(pair) for pair in zip(a,b)]` to make it as list of list.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. One method is to use [List Comprehension Syntax](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html). List Comprehension will give you the most control, but is a little hard to grasp. The easiest way would be to use the built in `zip()` function; see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). The zip function essentially takes two lists and combines them into a single list.